# Change format of Datetime - sql and asp.net mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to insert a record with a `datetime` field. The format that sql has is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` I'm using SQL Server 2012

In `DateTime.Now` what I'm getting is `02/10/2017 16:58:23`

Is there any for me to change the format of the `DateTime.Now` from `DD/MM/YYYY` to `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? datetime is a product specific data type.

Comment: `DateTime` is a struct, it doesn't have formatting standard. The date what you need is just string representation of `DateTime`, which can be inserted to DB depending database & data type you're using (avoid using `varchar` to store `DateTime` value).

Comment: Keep everything in `datetime` variables/parameters on both the .NET and SQL Server side and let ADO.Net take care of the translation. Neither .NETs `DateTime` nor SQL Server's `datetime` *have* a format. Internally, they both just store a count of the number of intervals since a particular epoch date. You'll only *have* formatting issues if you give in to the temptation to start treating them as/converting them to *strings*.

Comment: You can use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` to convert into desired format, but keep in mind this is just *string representation* - neither `DateTime` struct nor `datetime`/`datetime2` SQL data type has standard date format (every date & time elements stored as separate integer properties). Use date string formatting just for display purpose in view page.

Answer (score 0):

To change `Datetime` to your desired format you can use `GetDateTimeFormats` function which takes `format` as parameter.
You can read more about this on : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyk2998w(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS")
```